# Xamarin BindableProperty works with binding only when I don't use BindingContext

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

in Xamarin Forms I created a Page that contains a custom component which I want to feed a value just like this:

```
<c:CustomComponent Test="{Binding Test}" />
```

This, however, doesn't work. When I use a raw number instead of the Binding it works. The problem that I figured out was, that my custom component used a ViewModel / BindingContext. So when I remove the line where I assign my ViewModel to the BindingContext the Binding works.

why is that so and how can I use use both, the BindingContext as well as BindableProperty within my custom component? Or do I have to do everything within my code behind?

For reference some code example how I created the BindableProperty

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Test), typeof(int),
    typeof(CustomComponent), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
        Debug.WriteLine("TEST " + newVal);
    });

public int Test {
    get => (int)GetValue(TestProperty);
    set => SetValue(TestProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: To explain what is going on, show more xaml/code. Sounds like confusion between **page**'s BindingContext, and **component's** BindingContext. Please show a **complete (but minimal) example** of the problem. A simple page that includes the component. The page's code behind - does the page have a BindingContext? A ViewModel? Then a simplified version of the CustomComponent, both xaml and code. But you have stumbled upon the key fact: Its easier to work with a CustomComponent if it is self-contained, does not refer to a separate viewmodel. (The page can still have a VM.)

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. but no, I really mean the BindingContext of the CustomComponent. The page itself has a ViewModel, which is used to pass the information to the component (as seen in my example). I will try to come up with a minimal example. cheers

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I created a new default project (Tabbed App) on VS and created two example components, one using a BindingContext, the other one without. The code is on GitHub: https://github.com/tagtraeumer/xamarin-issue-customcomponent-binding
these components are used in the browse page. As u can see the component without ViewModel shows the item name, the component with a ViewModel is blank on this position. A random number is displayed there which originates from the VM

Comment: I understand. I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "my custom component used a ViewModel / BindingContext."

Its easier to create a reusable custom component, if it is "self-contained" - no BindingContext.

Constructor:

```cs
public CustomComponent()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Move EVERYTHING you currently have in the component's viewmodel, into the xaml.cs code behind file.

Now in CustomComponent.xaml, give it a name (here `theComponent`):

```xml
<ContentView ...
 x:Name="theComponent"
 x:Class=...>
```

This comes in handy when component's xaml wants to bind to a property in itself:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding TestString, Source={x:Reference theComponent}}" />
```

```cs
public string TestString
{
    get => _testString;
    set {
        _testString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private string _testString = "test";
```

**tl;dr:** If component has an `x:Name="theComponent"` in its xaml, can use `{Binding ..., Source={x:Reference theComponent}}`, to refer to its own properties. No BindingContext needed.

---

If you want the component to have an associated ViewModel, with the above technique you don't have to set BindingContext to that VM. Do it like this:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string TestString
    {
        get => _testString;
        set {
            _testString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _testString = "test";
}
```

CustomComponent:

```cs
public MyViewModel VM { get; private set; }
public CustomComponent()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VM = new MyViewModel();
}
```

Usage in xaml:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding VM.TestString, Source={x:Reference theComponent}}" />
```

Comment: thanks, I guess I can work with the last solution. I tested it with the VM and changing the value and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to use viewmodel with ObservableObject from community toolkit? So we can leverage all the code gen and [RelayCommand], etc?

Comment: Yes, `public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject` works fine. Just be sure to write xaml similar to code snippet at end of answer.